# confluentinc/cp-kafka docker log4j warnings

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, log4j, confluent-platform

```
docker pull confluentinc/cp-kafka
```

I use this code to pull the kafka image.
Then, use the following to start the containers.

```
docker run --rm -d --name kafka-server -p 9092:9092 -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=192.168.1.164:2181 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 confluentinc/cp-kafka
```

However, it will immediately shut down and given the logs:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.ZookeeperReadyCommand).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

How to solve this log4j error? (By terminal)

Comment: Well - I tried to run same cmd `docker run - ... ntinc/cp-kafka` command and It did succeed.

Comment: Try by setting `stop_grace_period ` link https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Comment: @Gupta Hi, thanks for replying, you mean you use the command "docker pull confluentinc/cp-kafka" and then 'docker run - ... ntinc/cp-kafka ??

Comment: No Just run `docker run --rm -d --name kafka-server -p 9092:9092 -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=192.168.1.164:2181 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 confluentinc/cp-kafka`

Comment: Did you notice you have `--rm` in your command.

Answer (score 0):

You fix it by providing `KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS` variable. For example

```
-e KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS="kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
```

Note: `ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes` is for `bitnami/kafka` image, not Confluent ones